# Why can't I write to this Samba share from Windows?

Tags: raspberry-pi, samba, shared-folders

I'm using Raspbian on a pi zero. I can read all of the files but can't write to anything. I have set up a samba share at /home/piuser/share.
I have the current smb.conf

```
[Sensor-1]
comment=Sensor #1
path=/home/piuser/share
writeable=yes
create mask=0777
directory mask=0777
public=no
writeable=yes
browseable=yes
```

I have created a smbpasswd for the user piuser with

```
smbpasswd -a username
```

I have tried it with `force user` and `force group` set to both piuser and root, neither with any luck writing.

I have chmodded the entire home/piuser directory 777 recursively

I don't know what else to try.

Comment: Have you tried adding `security = user`? Or are you already getting an authorization prompt on windows?

Comment: Usually your first step with a problem like this is to check the logs.  I would check for log files in `/var/log/smba/` or see here for configuring logging: https://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Configuring_Logging_on_a_Samba_Server